# Spanish words for cap, cover, lid, etc

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, definiciones

What Spanish words can be used to describe a cap, cover, lid, or top (in other words, something placed on top of something, usually to close an opening)? What is the difference between *tapa* and *tapón*? What other words describe this concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what RAE says:

> tapa
>   1. f. Pieza que cierra por la parte superior cajas o recipientes.
>
> tapón.
>   1. m. Pieza con que se tapan las vasijas, introduciéndola en el orificio por donde sale el líquido.

So *tapa* is a generic cover, whereas a *tapón* is usually introduced in, or screwed on the hole it covers. Of course, it is not only used for vessels.

The word "cover" can be translated as *cubierta*, but I would say that a *cubierta* covers the whole object it protects.

Comment: As the definition you posted for *tapon* it goes in the hole where the liquid comes out. Not screwed on the bottle.

Comment: Yes, but the dictionary doesn't always include all uses of a word. By the way, when I wrote screwed on, I meant "enroscado", but I'm not sure it's the best choice. [These](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-iRyL1NhH5kY/Tuth0Akf8DI/AAAAAAAADWw/mwa1ejPGwhc/s1600/7-reciclaje-plastico-tapones-de-botellas-de-refrescos-de-diferenets-colores-cocacola-fanta-sprite-naranja-limon-reciclar-contenedores-ecologismo-contaminacion-ahorro-1.jpg) are called "tapones" in Spain, and are certainly not inserted on the bottle.

Answer (score 5):

*Tapa* Is a lid or cover it basically goes on the outside or top of the container. Where *Tapon* goes on the inside of the top of container. "Los vinos buenos tinen un tapon de corcho y los baratos tinen una tapa."

Comment: "Tapón" is also used for the screw-on caps (for example the one in a plastic bottle of coke), an it doesn't go on the inside of the container.

Comment: @Javi: not everywhere; at least not in Colombia. For the caps on a bottle of coke we never use *tapón* but *tapa*.